# Referencing a .net 4 library via COM in vs2005

Tags: c++, .net-4.0, com, visual-studio-2005

I have a visual studio 2005 c++ project  (that uses QT framework). I would like to reference and use a .net 4 library that I have via COM. I know that if I have a .net project (.net 2 or .net 3.5) in 2005, I cannot reference the .net 4 library but I am curious to know if I would have any issues trying to use it in a c++ project thru COM. I'm not at a point were I can create and test a proof-of-concept application yet so I was wondering if anyone else has tried this or know anything about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using COM is a fine way to get the CLR loaded so you can execute managed code.  But you'll have to use COM programming techniques in the C++ code.  Using Add Reference doesn't work, that's a option that's only available if you write managed code in the C++/CLI language.

One good way is to use the [#import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in your C++ code.  That can load a type library and auto-generates smart pointer types and method wrappers that you can directly call in your C++ code.  Generate the type library you need with the Tlbexp.exe utility or the Regasm.exe /tlb command line option.  QT has built-in COM support as well, I don't know enough about it.